# Being amazed at an adverb: subjunctive necessary?

Tags: grammar-choice, conjunctive

Which is correct for "I am amazed at how fast it moves"?

> Miror quam celeriter movetur.

or

> Miror quam celeriter moveatur.

I'm thinking that since the *movere* verb is finite and subordinate to *miror*, as well as introduced with no conjunction, it should be in the subjunctive. Then again, it denotes a reality, not a thought or a hypothesis or a consequence.

Comment: It's often possible to rephrase using a different part of speech, e.g. *celeritas*. But it's not always available or flexible, so your question is good even I there's a workaround for the specific example.

Comment: The construction is indirect question, so subjunctive moveatur is needed.